# Create a Geoserver layer with data from a Postgis SQL view with Python/gsconfig

Tags: python, postgis, geoserver

I'm trying to get a Python program, using gsconfig api, to create dynamically a Geoserver layer with data from a native SQL (like you do on the Geoserver web interface).

I can create the workspace and the datastore, but I can't figure out how to create a layer with a sql view of the Postgis database (example: select * from *table* where _filter_clause_).

This is the current Python code that I have.

```
from geoserver.catalog import Catalog

if __name__ == '__main__':

    cat = Catalog("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest", username = "admin", password = "geoserver")

    ws = cat.get_workspace ("wsProva")
    if ws is None:
        ws = cat.create_workspace('wsProva','wsProva')

    ds = cat.get_store ("dsProva", "wsProva")
    if ds is None:
        ds = cat.create_datastore('dsProva','wsProva')

    ds.connection_parameters.update (host='localhost', port='5432', database='dbtest', user='userdb', passwd='pwddb', dbtype='postgis', schema='postgis')
    cat.save(ds)
```

I've googled a lot about this issue, but I haven't found anything useful for me. Thanks a lot for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

2020 update,

You can simply use [geoserver-rest](https://pypi.org/project/geoserver-rest/) library (`pip install geoserver-rest`). The example case is below,

```py
#import and initialize library
from geo.Geoserver import Geoserver
geo = Geoserver('http://localhost:8080/geoserver', username='admin', password='geoserver')


# create feature store and publish layer
geo.create_featurestore(store_name='geo_data', workspace='demo', db='postgres', host='localhost', pg_user='postgres', pg_password='admin')
geo.publish_featurestore(workspace='demo', store_name='geo_data', pg_table='geodata_table_name')
```

Comment: Is any way to specify the Declared SRS when publishing a layer? Can we use geoserver-rest library with SQL Server?

Comment: I think geoserver will take the srs from postgres. You can specify the srs in database directly and just use the "publish_featurestore" method.